# jquery :selecting the radio button by tr

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

My table  is like followed, i want to select the radio button(style="display: table-row;") in this table,but because of toggle my previous "n" no of radio button is hidden(style display none) and  radio button(style="display: table-row;") is appear as first one in gui but in table it's "n+1" one radio-button(if n no of radiobuttons are display:none).,please any one can help,thank-you.

```
<html>
<title></title>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="hidden_source2">
    <table id="return_me" class="tbl2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="rower" style="display: none;">
    <td width="4">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="30">
    <input class="return_r" type="radio" name="return">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rower" style="display: none;">
    <td width="4">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="30">
    <input class="return_r" type="radio" name="return">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rower" style="display: none;">
    <td width="4">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="30">
    <input class="return_r" type="radio" name="return">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rower" style="display: table-row;">
    <td width="4">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="30">
    <input class="return_r" type="radio" name="return">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rower" style="display: table-row;">
    <td width="4">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="30">
    <input class="return_r" type="radio" name="return">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rower" style="display: table-row;">
    <td width="4">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="30">
    <input class="return_r" type="radio" name="return">
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you want to select/check first radio button in the table. You can achieve this using [:first selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/).

```
$("table#return_me input:radio:first").attr('checked', true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4hR55/

Comment: actuvally because of toggle my first radio button style is none it is hidden my second radio button appear as first one in gui can you explain how to solve this...

Comment: I did not get you. Do you want to show/hide second radio button on check/uncheck of first radio button?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eq()`.  It is zero-based, so 1 grabs the second `input` (but the first visible).

`$('input').eq(1).attr('checked','true');`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/YNyCj/

Details on `eq` here: http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: thank you sir ..if the table contain more hiddens("<tr class="rower" style="display: none;">
    <td width="4">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="30">
    <input class="return_r" type="radio" name="return">
    </td>
") at that time how we can select the radio button

Comment: You would just need to change the number in `.eq()`.